# There is no "ClassPath" in Configure Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-classpath

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pG0v.jpg)

I need to add an External Jar to the Classpath of my File, but the Classpath is nowhere to be Found in the Build Path menu

Comment: I thought that the eclipse IDE will use the buildpath as the classpath, otherwise check the run configurations page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everything on that tab is the Classpath. You only see separate Classpath/Modulepath for Java 9 or later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a Modulepath for Java 1.8, so everything you see is for the Classpath.